# Why i get the error <Error: Cannot update an unmounted root.> when mounting and unmounting a comonent dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dom

i want to mount and unmount a modal dynamically using a hook

```
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('modals')!);

const Modal = <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h1>;

export default function useModal() {
    const [up, setUp] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (up) root.render(Modal);
        else queueJob(() => root.unmount());
    }, [up]);

    return [up, setUp] as const;
}
```

and in my app

```
const App = () => {
    const [up, setUp] = useModal();

    return (<button onClick={() => setUp(v => !v)}>show modal</button>);
};
```

and when i click on this button i get the error

`Uncaught Error: Cannot update an unmounted root.`

am i doing something wrong ? any help, thanks in advance

Comment: Where does this `queueJob` function come from?  The error occurs on the first render, where the modal has never been mounted and `up` is `false`, so the `useEffect` hook will call the `root.unmount()` function.  You'll need some sort of conditional check here.

Comment: @LindaPaiste ah that function is this


const queueJob = (job) => {
    setTimeout(job);
};

Comment: @LindaPaiste actually even if i have true as an initial state i get the same issue on the second render

Comment: Yeah after leaving that comment I played with your code a bit and I could not get it working  :( I could get it to show and hide once but not to show again after hiding. So I'm not qualified to answer this one.